# Populating the join table in a HABTM relationship using the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
class Institute < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :institutes
end
```

I have a join table "institutes_user". Using the Rails console, how do I automatically populate this table when I create a new User that belongs to a specific Institute (assuming it already exists)?

When I use the "create" method from the rails console to create a User (and pass in the institute_id), it does not populate the join table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "shovel" operator.  For example,

```
Institute.first.users << User.new(first_name: "A", last_name: "B", email: "C")
```

will insert a new `User` record on the `users` table and a new join row on the `institute_users` table.

You can see a list of other methods added to your classes through `has_and_belongs_to_many` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference).

Comment: Thanks, how do I pass in values?
I want to do something like:
User.create(first_name: "A", last_name: "B", email: "C")

Comment: When I do the following:
Institute.find(1).users << User.create(first_name: "A", last_name: "B", email: "C")

I get the error: "Institute.find(1).users << User.create(first_name: "A", last_name: "B", email: "C")"

Comment: @user1175969, the solution code should work, both for `new` and `create`.  The error you posted in your comment is cut off.  Can you add it to your question?  Also can you specify your rails/ruby version?

Comment: My bad, it works now. I had an error in my model. Thanks!